# how to create Bar Charts and change the number to string values?

Tags: ios, swift2, swiftcharts

I have create the Bar Charts in ViewController using SwiftCharts framework, and i get the graph and bar charts below,

[image]

graph X Values are showed numbers but i need to change the string value (Example: 1 changed to BMW, 3 changed to Audi, 4 changed to Bens, 6 changed to Maruthi) how, and my code is given below,

```
import UIKit
import SwiftCharts

class BarViewController: UIViewController {

    private var chart: Chart?

    let sideSelectorHeight: CGFloat = 50

    private func barsChart(horizontal horizontal: Bool) -> Chart {
        let tuplesXY = [(1, 8), (3, 2), (4, 4), (6, 6)]

        func reverseTuples(tuples: [(Int, Int)]) -> [(Int, Int)] {
            return tuples.map{($0.1, $0.0)}
        }

        let chartPoints = (horizontal ? reverseTuples(tuplesXY) : tuplesXY).map{ChartPoint(x: ChartAxisValueInt($0.0), y: ChartAxisValueInt($0.1))}

        let labelSettings = ChartLabelSettings(font: ExamplesDefaults.labelFont)

        let (axisValues1, axisValues2) = (
            0.stride(through: 10, by: 2).map {ChartAxisValueDouble(Double($0), labelSettings: labelSettings)},
            0.stride(through: 7, by: 1).map {ChartAxisValueDouble(Double($0), labelSettings: labelSettings)}
        )
        let (xValues, yValues) = horizontal ? (axisValues1, axisValues2) : (axisValues2, axisValues1)

        let xModel = ChartAxisModel(axisValues: xValues, axisTitleLabel: ChartAxisLabel(text: "Product Details", settings: labelSettings))
        let yModel = ChartAxisModel(axisValues: yValues, axisTitleLabel: ChartAxisLabel(text: "Sales Percentage", settings: labelSettings.defaultVertical()))

        let barViewGenerator = {(chartPointModel: ChartPointLayerModel, layer: ChartPointsViewsLayer, chart: Chart) -> UIView? in
            let bottomLeft = CGPointMake(layer.innerFrame.origin.x, layer.innerFrame.origin.y + layer.innerFrame.height)

            let barWidth: CGFloat = Env.iPad ? 60 : 30

            let (p1, p2): (CGPoint, CGPoint) = {
                if horizontal {
                    return (CGPointMake(bottomLeft.x, chartPointModel.screenLoc.y), CGPointMake(chartPointModel.screenLoc.x, chartPointModel.screenLoc.y))
                } else {
                    return (CGPointMake(chartPointModel.screenLoc.x, bottomLeft.y), CGPointMake(chartPointModel.screenLoc.x, chartPointModel.screenLoc.y))
                }
            }()
            return ChartPointViewBar(p1: p1, p2: p2, width: barWidth, bgColor: UIColor.blueColor().colorWithAlphaComponent(0.6))
        }

        let frame = ExamplesDefaults.chartFrame(self.view.bounds)
        let chartFrame = self.chart?.frame ?? CGRectMake(frame.origin.x, frame.origin.y, frame.size.width, frame.size.height - sideSelectorHeight)
        let coordsSpace = ChartCoordsSpaceLeftBottomSingleAxis(chartSettings: ExamplesDefaults.chartSettings, chartFrame: chartFrame, xModel: xModel, yModel: yModel)
        let (xAxis, yAxis, innerFrame) = (coordsSpace.xAxis, coordsSpace.yAxis, coordsSpace.chartInnerFrame)

        let chartPointsLayer = ChartPointsViewsLayer(xAxis: xAxis, yAxis: yAxis, innerFrame: innerFrame, chartPoints: chartPoints, viewGenerator: barViewGenerator)

        let settings = ChartGuideLinesDottedLayerSettings(linesColor: UIColor.blackColor(), linesWidth: ExamplesDefaults.guidelinesWidth)
        let guidelinesLayer = ChartGuideLinesDottedLayer(xAxis: xAxis, yAxis: yAxis, innerFrame: innerFrame, settings: settings)

        return Chart(
            frame: chartFrame,
            layers: [
                xAxis,
                yAxis,
                guidelinesLayer,
                chartPointsLayer]
        )
    }

    private func showChart(horizontal horizontal: Bool) {
        self.chart?.clearView()

        let chart = self.barsChart(horizontal: horizontal)
        self.view.addSubview(chart.view)
        self.chart = chart
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.showChart(horizontal: false)

    }
```

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Just check the examples, there's one with text labels https://github.com/i-schuetz/SwiftCharts/blob/master/Examples/Examples/NotNumericExample.swift

Comment: Thanks its ok, but this example get x value is text and i need y value is number, if the example two values are text only show, how to change x value is text, y value is number?(example: x - Audi,BMW,Bens,Maruthi, y - 0,2,4,6,8,10)

Comment: Just use text for one axis and numbers for the other. This means, instead of using `stride` to generate the x values you create a hardcoded sequence of `ChartAxisValueString` with the strings you need and internal numbers (these can be simply 1,2,3...). Then you  have to ensure that the number you use for the x coordinate of the chartpoints belongs to the internal numbers you used for the axis. I'd recommend also you remove the code to switch between horizontal and vertical bars, if you only need vertical, to make it more understandable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have not worked with this library but I think the data which is inputted as tuple can be changed. Like this

```
("BMW":8), ("AUDI": 4)
```

The type of a tuple is determined by the values it has.

Hope it helps.

Comment: yes manully its ok, but how to send the string to tuple and also i need to show the graph(values BMW,Audi)

Comment: From where are you getting the list of the strings?

Comment: Its a framework? its only get number(variable name: tuplesXY), my question is how to send list string to tuplesXY?

Comment: Instead of hardcoded value you have to use custom value. Are you asking how to add tuple values dynamically? And did you try giving value manually? is it working?